# NSView - how can i redraw a subview without redrawing the parent view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a NSView with a sub view. I want to be able to redraw the sub view (call its drawRect) without redrawing the parent view. Is that possible?

When i case setNeedsDisplay on he sub view, drawRect of the parent view also called.

Comment: In addition to NSResponder's answer, I'd say: "what the parent view does when yours redraws is [supposed to be] none of your business." That's the drawing contract you have with Cocoa. If the parent view is one of your own classes, post its relevant drawing code and ask for optimization suggestions.

Comment: Both parent view and sub view are my own views. I implement theirs drawRect method. Most of the time the parent stays the same and only the sub view changes. For that reason i want only sub view's drawRect method to be called

Comment: The point is that your subview has no business telling your superview what to do. The superview needs to handle its own stuff and draw when the system tells it it's necessary. One way to avoid is to follow NSResponder's advice if your subview can indeed be opaque. If there're transparency layers between them, however, of course the superview will need to redraw at least that region.

Comment: (running out of room) That's why I asked about your superview's code - if it's really that big a performance hit, then your superview's drawRect: code could be optimized to only draw the necessary regions (using the rect passed in) if you haven't already. We won't know unless you post your code.

Comment: As Joshua mentioned, you must keep track of the dirty rect and draw only the regions that do not intersect subview's frame.

Comment: @cocoafan Or, draw only the region that *does* intersect the subview's frame, if the superview is providing a background to go behind the subview that needs to be redrawn. That's what I think @Joshua was getting at. Either way brings us back to the essential definition of `drawRect:`: Draw the section that lies within that rectangle, whatever it is, and ideally nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do to reduce unnecessary drawing is overide `-isOpaque` and return  YES.

Of course, you should only do this if the subview is in fact opaque.

Comment: What does it mean that the sub view is opaque?

Comment: You could also simply set the opaque property to YES. No need to overwrite the method. Opaque means "not transparent".

Comment: what will be the result of doing so?

Comment: If your -isOpaque method returns YES, then you are responsible for filling in the entirety of the rectangle you're passed in -drawRect:.  If this is the case, then the superview won't need to redraw to ensure correct results.

Comment: Well, really, you're responsible for filling the entirety of your view's *-bounds*, not just the rect you're passed (which is all the system is telling you needs to be redrawn).

Comment: No, your bounds can be bigger than the visible area of your view.

Comment: That's interesting. Under what circumstances is this the case? I've never encountered a custom view that didn't have the same bounds as its visible area. At least, I don't *think* I have.

Comment: The contentview of a scrollview is the most obvious example.  Its bounds  can be many times larger than its visible area.